# Incremental sync ignores the original filters

Tags: google-calendar-api

We manage our calendars syncs in this way -

1. running first sync with some filtering (timeMin & timeMax), then obtaining the `nextSyncToken`
2. running incremental syncs when triggered by the events watcher.
   The incremental syncs ignores the original filters and returns updated events from different dates.

Is this the expected behavior?

example - running first sync on dates `2021-07-25T00:00:00 - 2021-07-25T20:00:00`, getting `nextSyncToken = xxxxx`. adding a new event on 2021-08-08. running the incremental sync with `nextSyncToken = xxxxx`, returns that new event although it should have been filtered out. (tested on nodejs & on Google's api reference page)

Per Jose request, this is the requests & responses:

First request:

```
calendarId: ******,
q: importantEventsQuery,
timeMax: 2021-07-25T20:00:00+03:00,
timeMin: 2021-07-25T10:00:00+03:00
```

First response:

```
{
"kind": "calendar#events",
"etag": "\"p320******\"",
"summary": "a******",
"updated": "2021-08-09T04:39:45.696Z",
"timeZone": "******",
"accessRole": "owner",
"defaultReminders": [
    {
       "method": "popup",
       "minutes": 15
      }
],
"nextSyncToken": "**********uAE=",
"items": []
}
```

Second request:

```
calendarId: ******,
syncToken: **********uAE=
```

Second response:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p320cltebhuhv40g\"",
 "summary": "alon.sade@verizonmedia.com",
 "updated": "2021-08-09T04:39:45.696Z",
 "timeZone": "Asia/Jerusalem",
 "accessRole": "owner",
 "defaultReminders": [
  {
   "method": "popup",
   "minutes": 15
  }
 ],
 "nextSyncToken": "**********uAE=",
 "items": []
}
```

*Now I'm adding a new event on different date than the request and without the "importantEventsQuery" term*

Third request: equals to the second.

Third response:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p32k******\"",
 "summary": "******",
 "updated": "2021-08-09T06:42:13.241Z",
 "timeZone": "******",
 "accessRole": "owner",
 "defaultReminders": [
  {
   "method": "popup",
   "minutes": 15
  }
 ],
 "nextSyncToken": "*****=",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"******\"",
   "id": "******",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=******",
   "created": "2021-08-09T06:42:12.000Z",
   "updated": "2021-08-09T06:42:12.725Z",
   "summary": "dd",
   "creator": {
    "email": "******",
    "self": true
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "******",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2021-08-09T08:30:00+01:00"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2021-08-09T09:00:00+01:00"
   },
   "iCalUID": "******",
   "sequence": 0,
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   },
   "eventType": "default"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: As you mentioned, the calendar is being changed by adding a new event, have you checked if this `nextSyncToken` has changed?

Comment: When I'm getting the new result (with the unrelated events), its `nextSyncToken` is new and different

Comment: As I see in the responses it's not the intended behavior, if there's no report related already filed I'd open a new one. https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/support#problems_errors

Answer (score 0):

### This is normal so as to keep data consistent

That is the expected behaviour because you are adding a new resource and in order to keep consistency it might re-order that result.

If you want to keep your App consistent I strongly recommend you that whenever you add a resource, try to make a new request including the filters.

Take a look into [Events: list > syncToken property](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) where it states `It makes the result of this list request contain only entries that have changed since then` meaning you should make a new request at every change as previously said.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! - what do you mean by "adding a new resource"? a new event was added to the same calendar of the original request. In addition, I can't add time range filters when I'm using the the `nextSyncToken`. As for the quote from the documentation, isn't the assumption that the returned entries since the last query will still use the same constraints ?

Comment: I mean as you said "adding a new event on 2021-08-08" you are adding a new resource here. When you say that "it should have been filtered out" the reason why the filters are not reflected by using the `nextSyncToken` previously generated (before adding that event) is what I explain in my answer. I don't understand what do you mean by "I can't add time range filters when I'm using the nextSyncToken".

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that events are resources. what's the purpose of the `nextSyncToken` and running an incremental syncs if it ignores the filters and returning the new (unrelated) resources in the results?   As for the adding time range, you suggested that "whenever you add a resource, try to make a new request including the filters", I don't want to do a full sync for each new event, I'm trying to run incremental syncs as describe here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/sync

Comment: Is it possible to see the full payload (request / response)?

Comment: I've added the requests and responses, thanks!